# Unable to update the JSON Node with a String value

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a JSON file and the node it looks like this

```
"my_location": [
      {
        "my_address_type": "ZZZ", //changed
        "my_address-street": "601 XX street", //changed
        "my_address-suburb": "XXX", //changed
        "my_address-postcode": "XX", //changed
        "my_address-state": "XX" //changed
      }
    ]
```

and I have a string ( say string2 ) value which is like below

```
"    {
    "my_address_type": "AAA",
    "my_address-street": "601 XX street", 
    "my_address-suburb": "XXX",
    "my_address-postcode": "XX",
    "my_address-state": "XX"
  },{
    "my_address_type": "BBB", //changed
    "my_address-street": "601 XX street",
    "my_address-suburb": "XXX",
    "my_address-postcode": "XX",
    "my_address-state": "XX"
}"
```

please see the double qoutes in the above string. My requirement is I need to update/replace the values within the my_location node to the new string ( here string2).

I use the below code to update the JSONNode

```
jsonObj[//node of my_location]= string2
```

I am struck here as the whole content after updating reads like below

```
"my_location": [
"    {
"my_address_type": "AAA",
"my_address-street": "601 XX street", 
"my_address-suburb": "XXX",
"my_address-postcode": "XX",
"my_address-state": "XX"
 },{
"my_address_type": "BBB", //changed
"my_address-street": "601 XX street",
"my_address-suburb": "XXX",
"my_address-postcode": "XX",
"my_address-state": "XX"
}"
]
```

Hence the system treats this as a string and not as a array of values. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

I believe this is quite achievable using a simple line. But not able to crack it. Thanks again for your help

The C# Code is below

```
string RequestData = File.ReadAllText("UpdatedRecord.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(RequestData);
jsonObj[allNode[0]][allNode[1]][0][allNode[2]][0]=string2
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

I wish to have the below desired output.

Please see that the double quotes " removed

```
"my_location": [
// " - WISH THIS IS REMOVED
    {
"my_address_type": "AAA",
"my_address-street": "601 XX street", 
"my_address-suburb": "XXX",
"my_address-postcode": "XX",
"my_address-state": "XX"
 },{
"my_address_type": "BBB", //changed
"my_address-street": "601 XX street",
"my_address-suburb": "XXX",
"my_address-postcode": "XX",
"my_address-state": "XX"
}
// " - WISH THIS IS REMOVED
]
```

Comment: Share C# code. This is only json

Comment: @GaurangDave - Thanks and have added the code.

Comment: What is `allNode` and how is it initialized?

Comment: Your question is still unclear, can you please share the desired output?

Comment: @JamesWhyte -   allNode is the string array and it contains the path to reach to a particular node in the JSON. Here, to arrive at my_location. It is something which is passed from a spreadsheet. it is not null and it holds  a value.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani  - Added Desired output. The issue is when I update the node jsonObj[//node of my_location]= string2 with the string, the array content is replaced with the string but not as array of Object. I need to somehow represent string2 as not string but array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a `dynamic` object

```
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(RequestData);
```

Make a class for the JSON like this.

```
public class MyLoc
{
    public string my_address_type { get; set; }
    public string my_address-street { get; set; }
    public string my_address-suburb { get; set; }
    public string my_address-postcode { get; set; }
    public string my_address-state { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can Deserialize your JSON

```
List<MyLoc> jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyLoc>>(RequestData);
```

I havent tested the above line as the JSON provided is not a valid JSON. 
Once the Deserialization is done successfully. Then just simply update the Object like this

```
jsonObj[1].my_address_type = "Whatever you Wish";
--------^----- is the node or index you want to change.
```

then Serialize the Object back to JSON to see your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to cast the whole string to array of MyLoc instance?

Comment: I wish I could have understood what you meant by *cast the whole string to array of MyLoc*. The issue is that the JSON provided is not a Valid JSON else just a copy paste would have helped you.